# Running GWT project from intelliJ IDEA 11

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

I was trying to debug a GWT project in intelliJ IDEA 11.

I can test the same project in command line using; ant devmode.

However, after i setup a intelliJ configuration and pressed debug, the page produced was:

```
HTTP ERROR: 404
NOT_FOUND
RequestURI=/StockWatcher.html

Powered by Jetty://
```

I am very new to GWT. Can someone help me with this?

Regads

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Please, make a screenshot of your 'Debug configuration' window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easiest to run a project in Development Mode from a war folder.

1. Create a war folder under the project root.
2. Add war/WEB-INF/web.xml if using RPC
3. Add -war <absolute path to war> to Dev Mode parameters.
4. Run

Comment: Do you mean in 3. absolute path to war folder? Because I'm having trouble with running existing GWT project in IDEA (runs OK from Eclipse), it has already war folder, but I'm not sure if that war folder contains right files.

Comment: I spent hours figuring out what was wrong, thank you for that advice, now everything works finally!

Comment: Why would you put an absolute path? That doesn't work well with other developers. Still, this soultion doesn't workf or me.